# Prolog basic exercise with lists gives stack size error

Tags: list, prolog, swi-prolog

I'm starting to learn prolog, and I'm stuck with this problem, it would be really helpful if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong and why is it wrong so I can learn.

### Exercise

Write a predicate that follows the syntax:

**supr_bigger(Elem,List,Result)**

where *Result* is the list *List*, but with all of the elements bigger than *Elem* deleted.

### Code

```
supr_bigger(_,[],[]).

supr_bigger(Elem,[X|Y],R) :- X =< Elem,
                                  insert(X,R,R1),
                                  supr_bigger(Elem,Y,R1).

supr_bigger(Elem,[X|Y],R) :- X > Elem, supr_bigger(Elem,Y,R).



insert(Z,L1,L2) :- choose(Z,L2,L1).


choose(X,[X|L],L).
choose(X,[Y|L1],[Y|L2]) :- choose(X,L1,L2).
```

When I try to test the code above, this error shows up: 
?- supr_bigger(3,[3,2,5,4,1,2,6],R).

**ERROR: Stack limit (1,0Gb) exceeded 

ERROR: Stack sizes: local: 2Kb, global: 0,9Gb, trail: 0Kb 

ERROR: Stack depth: 16, last-call:13%, Choice points: 11**

A lot of thanks in advance.

Comment: To start with, please replace `supr-bigger` by `supr_bigger`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use predicate [`trace/1`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=trace/1) to find out what is wrong with your code:

```
?- trace, supr_bigger(3, [3,2,1,4], R).
   Call: (11) supr_bigger(3, [3, 2, 1, 4], _4526) ? creep
   Call: (12) 3=<3 ? creep
   Exit: (12) 3=<3 ? creep
   Call: (12) insert(3, _4526, _5168) ? creep
   Call: (13) choose(3, _5210, _4526) ? creep
   Exit: (13) choose(3, [3|_4526], _4526) ? creep
   Exit: (12) insert(3, _4526, [3|_4526]) ? creep
   Call: (12) supr_bigger(3, [2, 1, 4], [3|_4526]) ? creep
   Call: (13) 2=<3 ? creep
   Exit: (13) 2=<3 ? creep
   Call: (13) insert(2, [3|_4526], _5482) ? creep
   Call: (14) choose(2, _5524, [3|_4526]) ? creep
   Exit: (14) choose(2, [2, 3|_4526], [3|_4526]) ? creep
   Exit: (13) insert(2, [3|_4526], [2, 3|_4526]) ? creep
   Call: (13) supr_bigger(3, [1, 4], [2, 3|_4526]) ? creep
   Call: (14) 1=<3 ? creep
   Exit: (14) 1=<3 ? creep
   Call: (14) insert(1, [2, 3|_4526], _5796) ? creep
   Call: (15) choose(1, _5838, [2, 3|_4526]) ? creep
   Exit: (15) choose(1, [1, 2, 3|_4526], [2, 3|_4526]) ? creep
   Exit: (14) insert(1, [2, 3|_4526], [1, 2, 3|_4526]) ? creep
   Call: (14) supr_bigger(3, [4], [1, 2, 3|_4526]) ? creep
   Call: (15) 4=<3 ? creep
   Fail: (15) 4=<3 ? creep
   Redo: (14) supr_bigger(3, [4], [1, 2, 3|_4526]) ? creep
   Call: (15) 4>3 ? creep
   Exit: (15) 4>3 ? creep
   Call: (15) supr_bigger(3, [], [1, 2, 3|_4526]) ? creep
   Fail: (15) supr_bigger(3, [], [1, 2, 3|_4526]) ?
```

As you can observe, when the input list is **empty** (call 15), the output list actually contains all the elements that should have been selected. However, the **base clause** in the recusive definition of `supr_bigger/3` **cannot** be applied in this case, since lists `[]` (clause's third argument) and `[1, 2, 3|_4526]` (goal's third argument) do not match.

To solve the problem, you could modify your code to:

- Close the open list `[1, 2, 3|_4526]`, transforming it into `[1, 2, 3]`.
- Add a new argument to collect the final result.

But, since your code has many other problems, it's better to try a **simpler approach**:

```
supr_bigger(_, [], []).
supr_bigger(B, [X|Xs], [X|Ys]) :- X =< B, supr_bigger(B, Xs, Ys).
supr_bigger(B, [X|Xs], Ys) :- X  > B, supr_bigger(B, Xs, Ys).
```

Example:

```
?- supr_bigger(3, [3,2,1,4], R).
R = [3, 2, 1] ;
false.
```

To **eliminate spurious choice points**, you can do as follows

```
supr_bigger(B, L, R) :-
    best_supr_bigger(L, B, R).

best_supr_bigger([], _, []).
best_supr_bigger([X|Xs], B, R) :-
    (   X =< B
    ->  R = [X|Ys]
    ;   R = Ys ),
    best_supr_bigger(Xs, B, Ys).
```

Example:

```
?- supr_bigger(3, [3,2,1,4], R).
R = [3, 2, 1].
```